# need sample of jquery treeview linked to SQL DB table updates

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sql, jquery-ui, .net-3.5

i have a self-referencing table in SQL 2005 of employees and want to generate a UI control that allows representation of the self-referencing employee data to users and allow then to change the relations of employees within the corporate hierarchy structure.

so that if a user notices they are now reporting to another manager they can drag their names to the correct location and this will update the DB so that the change is persisted to SQL.

I can take care of the SQL details and procs, but have never worked with JQUERY controls. any one can point me in a direction of a code sample for somethign like this?

Answer (score 0):

A pretty cool client-side grid with tree-view ability:

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki

and they have some nice examples:

http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html

Of course, you will need to build server-side web services to support it, but that will be the case with any AJAX control.

Comment: is this a paid item or free? also i dont see functionality to move nodes up and down.

Comment: It's free. And they have another example showing row re-ordering: http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example9-row-reordering.html

Comment: You will definitely have to do some research and get familiar with the control - it has lots of functionality but also requires some coding.